# Should a corporate intranet page use Top bar or Sidebar navigation?

Tags: navigation, menu, intranet, sidemenu

I'm a communications specialist working on a project that's redesigning our corporate intranet page.

The question I'm facing now is whether this is best done by having a responsive sidebar that would become "my menu" or by putting the "my menu" directly into the content of the main navigation menu (top bar) once it opens.

ft 365 (their calendar, agenda, recent files, contacts, etc) and wouldn't relate to the site architecture but just those tools.

Comment: Have you got any mockups? The answer is generally 'It Depends' so it's going to be hard to make any reasoned suggestions without knowing more details.